# Low Level Audio Engine Sample Rate Conversion

Tags: c++, algorithm, audio, interpolation, filtering

First off, there seems to be a sparse number of audio programming tutorials out there so if anyone knows of some good resources I would be very appreciative. Now on to the topic at hand!

I am using WASAPI for the audio engine that I am trying to develop and I am having difficulties reformatting data from a read audio file data into a format that the audio device is prepared to receive. Specifically I am wondering how games generally handle converting the sampling rate of a read audio file into the requested sampling rate of the device. I saw an example where linear interpolation was used but read elsewhere that such a filter introduces too many artifacts, so again I'm wondering what a practical algorithm would be for game design, something good enough that can be achievable in a high work load real time environment.

On a separate note, would it be safe to assume that most games store the majority of its audio assets in an uncompressed audio format to save the CPU the work of uncompressing the data or are there more benefits to be gained from having less data to load from the hard drive.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Sometimes reading a compressed asset off disc then decompressing is faster than reading the uncompressed data, since CPUs massively outpace the bandwidth of storage devices. The best way to find out is to profile your actual use case on your target hardware. You might find the [Sound Design StackExchange](https://sound.stackexchange.com/) has better answers for your sampling rate conversion question, if you'd like to ask there instead.

Comment: Thank you for your response and advisement; I didn't even know that there was a stack exchange specifically for sound and I will move the sample rate portion of my question over there.